# AWS EC2 Web Server Permission Denied

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, winscp

Hi I just installed AWS EC2 and successfully got Apache configured, setup the HOSTNAME= and was able to log into it with WinSCP

I can even upload files to my home/ec2-user folder no problem
however the webserver doesn't see my site from there.

Digging around I see the screenshot on the AWS site points to an image that has the remote directory be /var/www/html  however it will not allow me to upload files in there.

I saw other solutions to set permissions

```
chown -R ec2-user /var/www/
```

however this also gives an error.

I saw someone said 'be sure to log in as a root user' - isn't that what we're doing with the private key?

How do I point the web server to a folder that I can write to in order that my website is visible?

Thanks for your help. I'm sure others are frustrated as I am. SOOOO Close.

Perhaps the trick would be to upload my website to the /home/ec2-user folder and somehow configure apache to find the files there?

What do you recommend?

Comment: "This also gives an error" . It would be good if you could write what error you get to make it easier to locate the problem, that is what errors are for =) did you try "**sudo** chown -R..." ?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 8):

I missed an important step
[Install User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

```
sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

see
You would think that Amazon could provide a simple 'Install Wizard' batch file that simply does these above steps. I wonder how many people figure this out.

Comment: I've been a system admin for a long time. Simply finding the right commands is all that was needed to make this work.

Comment: I did know the sudo command. Was just missing the association of the ec2-user with the apache user.

Comment: amazing bro it worked after apply these commands . I was not able to enter the /html folder before but now its working

Comment: May I ask, for general knowledge, why when giving apache the permissions it worked, but on my case, for example, i did not do these 4 commands, and gave "ec2-user" the permissions on var/www/ and all went great except when trying to execute a php file that wanted to create a text file. the php code worked and everything great, just when trying to create a text file i got "permission denied". This solution solved it. I'm trying to understand why. What does the "apache" group has that "ec2-user" doesn't have